# Django filter manytomany results

Tags: python, django, model

Say that I have a many to many relationship field in my model, what I'm trying to do is get all the related entities if the field in the entity is equivalent to MAMMAL. I'm currently doing this in a list comprehension but wondering if there's a more elegant solution that django models provide.

```
[related_entity for related_entity in related_entity.related_entities.all() if
                                  related_entity.entity_type.entity_type_label == 'MAMMAL']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A many-to-many field gives you a manager, just like the standard `Model.objects()` one, and you can filter it in exactly the same way:

```
related_entity.filter(entity_type__entity_type_label="MAMMAL")
```

Comment: Ah Thanks! so when filtering should I always do model__field='somevalue'? I've been filtering model.field='value'.

Comment: No, it's for traversing relationships: it's `field__relatedfield='valueofrelatedfield'`. You didn't show your actual models so it's a bit hard to know whether you need that or not.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Django documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), you could use:

entity.objects.filter(related_entity__entity_type__entity_type_label == 'MAMMAL')